# Stored Procedure - Receive an int value returns nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to get the `NIC` number of employees and return their `FirstName`, `LastName`, `ProfCategory`, `AdmissionDate`. I created a procedure but when I try to declare the parameters, I get errors:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 620
> Must declare the scalar variable "@FirstName"
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 621
> Must declare the scalar variable "@FirstName"

My SQL code is this;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_EmployeeNIC
    @NIC int,
    @FirstName nvarchar(30) output,
    @LastName nvarchar(30) output,
    @ProfCategory nvarchar(30) output,
    @AdmissionDate date output
AS
    SELECT 
        @FirstName = FirstName,
        @LastName = LastName,
        @ProfCategory = ProfCategory, 
        @AdmissionDate = AdmissionDate  
    FROM 
        Employees
    WHERE 
        NIC = @NIC
```

I'm calling this stored procedure with this SQL statement:

```
DECLARE @FirstName nvarchar(30), @LastName nvarchar(30), 
        @ProfCategory nvarchar(30), @AdmissionDate date

EXEC sp_EmployeeNIC 12345, 
                    @FirstName OUTPUT, 
                    @LastName OUTPUT, 
                    @ProfCategory OUTPUT, 
                    @AdmissionDate OUTPUT

SELECT @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName + ' ' + @ProfCategory + ' ' + @AdmissionDate
```

And this is my table of Employees:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees 
(
    NIC int unique NOT NULL,
    FirstName nvarchar(30) NOT NULL, 
    LastName nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    ValidityNIC date NOT NULL,
    NIF int unique NOT NULL,
    IDNationality nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
    FullAddress nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PostalCode nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    DateOfBirth date NOT NULL,
    Username nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Passw nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Phone int NOT NULL,
    Email nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    ProfCategory nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    AdmissionDate date NOT NULL,
    EducationLv nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Salary money NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_eNic PRIMARY KEY (NIC),
    CONSTRAINT CK_BirthEmp CHECK ((YEAR(DateOfBirth)) < (YEAR(GETDATE()))),
    CONSTRAINT FK_eNationality 
        FOREIGN KEY (IDNationality) REFERENCES Nationalities (IDNationality)
)
```

**Update**

So I could solve my problem thanks to David's answer. Now I am trying to get NIC of all employees instead of writing as a parameter `12345`. How can I list all of `FirstName`,`LastName`, `ProfCategory`,`AdmissionDate` of employees?

I tried to write like this

```
DECLARE @NIC int, @FirstName nvarchar(30), @LastName nvarchar(30), 
        @ProfCategory nvarchar(30), @AdmissionDate date

EXEC sp_EmployeeNIC @NIC,
                    @FirstName, @LastName, @ProfCategory, @AdmissionDate

SELECT @NIC + ' ' + @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName + ' ' + @ProfCategory + ' ' + cast(@AdmissionDate  as varchar(20))
```

But I got a `NULL` value

Comment: simply `SELECT FirstName,LastName, ProfCategory,AdmissionDate FROM employees`. Return the result from your stored procedure and not via output parameter

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. How are you executing that ? you need to highlight only that 3 lines and F5 to execute in Query Window

Comment: Yes I got NULL value.. But I have 10 NIC values from Employees

Comment: you didn't pass in any value to `@NIC`. Add `SET @NIC = 12345` before `EXEC sp_EmployeeNIC`

Comment: But instead of just one Employees' NIC I want all of them to show in query

Comment: In that case, you can't use `OUTPUT` parameter as you will have multiple rows of result. Change your stored procedure to simply `SELECT FirstName,LastName, ProfCategory,AdmissionDate FROM employees` and remove all output parameter

Comment: I couldn't get it.. So I changed sp_EmployeeNIC only gettin `@NIC` parameter and than `AS BEGIN SELECT FROM NIC,FirstName,LastName,ProfCategory,AdmissionDate FROM Employees`
`WHERE @NIC = NIC` but saying **Incorrect syntax near 'NIC' **

Comment: @DaleK Sorry! I just discovered

Comment: @dtaskin please also revisit your earlier questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return all the employee and not only one single NIC. Remove the input and output parameters. Change the stored procedure to return a result set

```
CREATE PROC sp_EmployeeNIC
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT NIC, FirstName, LastName , ProfCategory, AdmissionDate  
    FROM   Employees
END
```

And to execute the stored procedure

```
exec sp_EmployeeNIC
```

Side note : avoid naming your stored procedure prefix with `sp_` see [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

> Avoid the use of the sp_ prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is
> used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix
> can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure
> with the same name.

Comment: Thank you so much! It solves my problem, funny that my professor wants as sp_name haha

Answer (score 0):

What you posted looks ok, except you never terminated the stored procedure. A stored procedure goes until the end of the batch.  eg

```
use tempdb
go
drop table if exists employees 

go
CREATE TABLE Employees (
    NIC int unique NOT NULL,
    FirstName nvarchar(30) NOT NULL, 
    LastName nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    ValidityNIC date NOT NULL,
    NIF int unique NOT NULL,
    IDNationality nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
    FullAddress nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PostalCode nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    DateOfBirth date NOT NULL,
    Username nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Passw nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Phone int NOT NULL,
    Email nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    ProfCategory nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    AdmissionDate date NOT NULL,
    EducationLv nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    Salary money NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_eNic PRIMARY KEY (NIC),
    --CONSTRAINT CK_BirthEmp CHECK ((YEAR(DateOfBirth))<(YEAR(GETDATE()))),
    --CONSTRAINT FK_eNationality FOREIGN KEY (IDNationality) REFERENCES Nationalities (IDNationality)
    )

go
CREATE OR ALTER PROC sp_EmployeeNIC
    @NIC int,
    @FirstName nvarchar(30) output,
    @LastName nvarchar(30) output,
    @ProfCategory nvarchar(30) output,
    @AdmissionDate date output
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT @FirstName = FirstName,@LastName = LastName ,@ProfCategory = ProfCategory, @AdmissionDate = AdmissionDate  FROM Employees
  WHERE NIC = @NIC
END

go
DECLARE @FirstName nvarchar(30), @LastName nvarchar(30), @ProfCategory nvarchar(30), @AdmissionDate date
EXEC sp_EmployeeNIC 12345,@FirstName output, @LastName output, @ProfCategory output, @AdmissionDate output
SELECT @FirstName + ' ' + @LastName + ' ' + @ProfCategory + ' ' + cast(@AdmissionDate  as varchar(20))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help! Normally I tried to get the NIC number of all employees and return their Names etc. I know that I should create a table inside of sp but how can I get just NIC of all employees instead of writing a single employees' NIC.